# Java: reading numbers from a .txt file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a .txt file of the of the form:

> Last game points:
>
> level 1º : 200
>
> Did you do well? :)

My goal is to read the points. In this example, it's 200. Here's what I've tried:

```
    public int[] points() throws FileNotFoundException {
    int[] points = new int[StaticUtils.LEVELS.size()];
    int next = 0;
    File file = new File("Points.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while(scanner.hasNextInt())
        points[next++] = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
    return points;
```

But this results in points being just zeros. That is, it's reading nothing from the file... How may I fix it?

Comment: Paste the exact contents of your Points.txt file please.

Comment: I did post @pczeus

Comment: I think it would be easier to read in the entire line scanner.nextLine() and then use String.split(":") to get the score.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should format the txt more readable. Ex:**level:point**

```
1:200
2:150
```

And you can read the string and parse it

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] arr = s.split(":");
        int level = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int point = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        points[level] = point;
    }
```

Comment: Yes! I guess that would work. The problem is that the contents of the .txt are to be shown in a GUI, when the player finishes the game. The user must know what the numbers mean. I'm thinking I might use an auxiliary .txt file, and then copy to the file used to inform the player.